# Spring Security: Check User Role in Freemarker template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm trying to check User Role in Freemarker template. I've try this:

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

And check roles by this:

```
<@security.authorize  access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    /*DO SOME STUFF*/
</@security.authorize>
```

But i got an error:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Error while looking for TLD file for "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"; see cause exception.
```

There is a lot of solutions in the Interned, I've try everything: Added dependencies in pom.xml, tried to change the link to taglibs etc.

But it didn't work, so how can i fix this or maybe there is another way to check User Role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally find solution for this.

You should use `access="hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')` or change your role from "ADMIN" to "ROLE_ADMIN" because `access="hasRole"` works only with roles named as ROLE first